# 'resignFirstResponder()' returns true and the text field loses focus but the keyboard does not dismiss

Tags: swift, keyboard, uitextfield, uiresponder, resignfirstresponder

I have a storyboard scene that only has two `UITextField`.The first one is left **untouched**, fresh out of the object library. The second one has its delegate outlet connected to the `ViewController`'s code.

[App's interface](http://1.contentlibrary.sinaapp.com/Connection.png)

[The second text field's connection in IB](http://1.contentlibrary.sinaapp.com/Connection.png)

(Sorry I have to post images this way, because StackOverflow won't let me.)

The code is really simple. This is all of it.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {    
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

The only thing it does is dismiss the keyboard when it's about to come up.

The first one shows the keyboard normally. The second one doesn't show keyboard because it's immediately dismissed.

It all works perfectly on their own, until I click the first text field to bring up the keyboard, then with the keyboard **on screen**, I click the second text field. 
What happens next, is that the second text field loses its focus, but the keyboard remains on screen.

Using `print(:)`, I've verified that, when I call `resignFirstResponder` on the second text field, it is the first responder, and the return value of that call is `true`, and after the call it is no longer the first responder.

But the keyboard is still there...

I tried adding `print(:)` in the delegate's `textFieldShouldReturn(:)` method, and clicking the return key after the text field resigned. There was nothing printed in the debug console.

I tried `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal()`, returning neither `false` nor `true` produces any difference.

## Edit

What I want is simple:
I want the first text field to do whatever it's default to do, and the second one to dismiss its keyboard as soon as it's tapped (from the user's perspective, basically meaning not showing it).

I know `textFieldShouldBeginEditing(:)`, but I can't use it for various reasons, I just have to **dismiss** the keyboard **after** it's been activated.

## Edit Again

I tried `view.endEditing(true)` as well. In fact, I tried `.endEditing(true)` on every view in the scene. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try smth like that:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    view.endEditing(true)
    return true
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    //make here whatever you like

}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't make my intentions clearer. I'm not interested in the behaviors of the first text field. I want to dismiss the keyboard for the second text field. And I've already tried endEditing. It doesn't seem to work. Please see my edits to the question.

Comment: It works! And replacing the for-in loop with an `endEditing(true)` call also works. Can you tell me why it works?

Comment: I changed it to view.Enditing(true) - is more clear :)

Comment: It works because textField become firstResponder in textFieldDidBeginEditing.